# $[\operatorname{Cos}(x)+i\operatorname{Sin}(x)]\cdot[\operatorname{Cos}(y)+i\operatorname{Sin}(y)]=\operatorname{Cos}(x+y)+i\operatorname{Sin}(x+y)$

Tags: complex-analysis

Had this **non**-analytic theorem ever been known before Euler discovered his analytic formula: $\operatorname{Cos}(x)+i\operatorname{Sin}(x)= e^{ix}$ ?

Please notice the distinction between, the theorem indicated in the title, and De Moivre's theorem - which is *not* about a *sum* of angles.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93691/discussion-on-question-by-eli-operatornamecosxi-operatornamesinx-cd).